# A performance issue with the Codility brackets challenge

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I am trying to solve the [Codility brackets](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/brackets/) challenge.
My solution is passing the *correctness* 100%, but it is failing at the *performance* tests.

From my point of view it should be O(n).

What is the time-consuming place?

- [Performance tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caayz.png)
- [Score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrNWR.png)

```
private class Solution
    {
        private Stack<char> _stack = new Stack<char>();
        private HashSet<char> _visited = new HashSet<char>() { '}', ']', ')' };

        private Dictionary<char, char> _dictionary = new Dictionary<char, char>()
        {
            { '{', '}' },
            { '[', ']' },
            { '(', ')' }
        };

        public int solution(String S)
        {
            if (S.Length % 2 != 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            foreach (char c in S)
            {
                if (_stack.Count > 0)
                {
                    var peek = _stack.Peek();
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Peek: {peek} - char: {c}");
                    if (GetOpposite(peek).Equals(c))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Pop {peek}");
                        _stack.Pop();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (_visited.Contains(c))
                            return 0;
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Push: {c}");
                        _stack.Push(c);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_visited.Contains(c))
                        return 0;
                    _stack.Push(c);
                }
            }


            return _stack.Count == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        }

        private char GetOpposite(char c)
        {
            return _dictionary[c];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the `'Debug.WriteLine'` lines ignored by the performance evaluator? Or conversely, are they required? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Comment: This is not Java: what is the `$` doing in `Debug.WriteLine($"foobar");` ? And `foreach` is not a valid keyword in Java. String does not have an implicit keyword `Length` but a method `length()`. Could you please add the correct language tag or add it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

As **Peter Mortensen** suggested.
Removed the "Debug.WriteLine" and got 100% performance score on same code.